# A Wiener-Ikehara variant with higher order poles

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, wieners-tauberian-theorem

**The problem**: I am concerned of getting a generalisation of the Wiener-Ikehara theorem for Dirichlet series which are analytic in the plane $\{s\in\mathbb{C}:\sigma>1\}$ and extend analytically over the line $\sigma=1,$ except for $1$, where they have a pole of order $k$ (not of order $1$ necessarily). I proved a generalisation in the following way. I added the extra assumption that the quotient

$$G(s)=\frac{F(s)}{{\zeta(s)}^k}$$

is represented by a Dirichlet series of non-negative coefficients for $\sigma>1$. Then, by induction on $k$, using the classical Wiener-Ikehara theorem (for a simple pole) for the initial induction step and applying the induction hypothesis on

$$H(s)=G(s){\zeta(s)}^{k-1},$$

I proved my assertion (the details are a bit technical with Abel summation). Although, I want to get a version of the above claim where the coefficients of $G$ might be negative.

**The question**: What kind of an assuption should I add to $G$ (for instance for its coefficients), in order to get a similar proof in this case?

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: @reuns It is given by $F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)n^{-s},$ if this is what you mean. If not, let me know. In my post I mean ordinary Dirichlet series. Maybe I should have mentioned it.

Comment: What is your concrete Dirichlet series, ie. what is $f$ ?

Comment: @reuns Nothing special. I am trying to get the result in general. I mean, it' s not $f(n)=2^{\nu (n)}$ or something like this.

Comment: If you are trying to get general result, then explain why, ie. what it is supposed to be useful for. The main steps are : the analytic continuation on the left of $\Re(s) = 1$, a bound there, plus Mellin inversion and a change of contour (ie. as in the prime number theorem).

Comment: @reuns Hmm... I expected something like it, but I was trying to avoid the cumbersome Perron-like formula methods. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @reuns, there is a whole field of Tauberian theory where minimal assumptions are put on $F(s)$, and in particular the usual analytic number theoretic trick of analytic continuation to the left of $\Re(s) = 1$ is *not* assumed. See, for example, Jacob Korevaar, *Tauberian Theory: A Century of Developments*.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks for the reference. I 'll check it out! Do you remember such a Tauberian Theorem in this book (like the one in my post)? I am asking, because I want to know if I can a proof of it in there.

Comment: Heh. If you read the book, you'll see why I can't answer your question: there are literally dozens of different formulations of Tauberian theorems, and I can't remember a particular one of the flavour that you're looking for.

Comment: @PeterHumphries OK, I 'll check them on my own.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Did you mean the function is not assumed analytic on an open set containing $\Re(s) \ge 1, s \ne 1$ ? This case is even more complicated and needs many assumptions on the behavior on $\Re(s) > 1$

Comment: @reuns, yup, there are a plethora of theorems dealing with such conditions; for example, if you only know absolute convergence for $\Re(s) > 1$ and that $F(s) \sim C/(s - 1)$ as $s \searrow 1$, then you can prove Tauberian theorems *additionally assuming* certain stringent conditions on the Dirichlet series coefficients.